# angular 2 Use Jasmine to inject a class with a mock http constructor

Tags: angular, http

I'm fairly new to Angular2 so please forgive if this is not worded quite right.

I am creating a unit test for a login component that injects an Authorization service.  The Authorization service uses http in the constructor.  So when I inject the Authorization service I need to include an instantiated http in the inject statement.  I've been tearing my hear out trying to figure out how and all the examples I've found are written in RC4-RC5 and no longer work.  Here is my code.

Authorization Class:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
private subject = new Subject<any>();

constructor(private http: Http) { }

login(username: string, password: string, rememberMe: boolean = false) {
    return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            /// A bunch of code
        }
...
```

The Unit Test (Jasmine)

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
let component: LoginComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
let authService: any;
let http: Http;

authService = new AuthenticationService(http);

beforeEach(async(() => {

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ FormsModule, RouterTestingModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
  providers: [
    fakeBackendProvider,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    {provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: authService},
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backend, options);
    }}
  ]
});

TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
 });
}));

it('Should show error "Invalid Username and Password." when the  username/password combination is not valid', () => {
 component.user.username = 'test';
 component.user.password = 'test';
 component.login();
 expect(component.errorMsg).toBe('Invalid Username and Password.');

});
```

I know that http has to be instantiated, but I can't find anyway to do it that works after RC5.  Also, I've already created an entire http fakebackendprovider that I use when demoing the app without a backend, so I'd prefer to use that anyway.  I just can't figure out how to do that.

```
export let fakebackendprovider = {
   provide: Http,
   useFactory: fakeBackend,
   deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
}
```